# Tensorflow Visual Studio import error

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow

I've been trying to install Tensorflow for the past 6 hours, and it's still not working. 
Googling resolved most issues including; the Install page on the website displaying the wrong wheel locations, getting CUDA loaded correctly, putting cuDNN.lib in the correct folders and NOT the ones described by NVidia.

When I activate tensorflow in cmd, and run the example code to verify functionality, I get this:

[image: 1]

You can see that the CUDA libraries are loaded correctly. If I then try to run this same script in the Spyder IDE that comes with Anaconda, I get:

[image: 2]]

So far, so good. I don't want to use Spyder though, I'd prefer to keep using Visual Studio. So I installed the python package for VS, and after a lot of tinkering and googling, managed to get VS to recognize and find the Anaconda compiler. When I run the same code as before, however, this is the result:

[image: 3]]

The last image doesn't show what happens when I F5, but it's as you'd expect if VS doesn't recognize a type: It can't resolve it. This is how I set up Anaconda3 in VS's "Python Environments":

[image: 4]]

Is there anything I can do, or is Visual Studio just not compatible with Anaconda and/or tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a separate CONDA environment (tensorflow) to install tensorflow which is used when you are trying Spyder and conda console.

But when you are accessing the Anaconda from Visual Studio it is only accessing the default ANACONDA environment. To select the tensorflow environment you need to specify the specific ENV

```
C:\Users\Tachyon\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\
C:\Users\Tachyon\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe
C:\Users\Tachyon\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\pythonw.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

today I had the same issue and tried to use Tensorflow in VS. Like you I tried it round about 6 h. Then I typed in Tensorflow in the packege search. There is Tensorflow as a seperate installer in VS [Package Tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YhK6.jpg). After I installed Tensorflow, the App is running fine.